# How can I customise the table of contents like so?

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

I face a problem of spacing between items in my table of contents. This is what I have at the moment:

[image]

I would like to change a few things:

1. I want to put table of content in center
2. I want to put single space between

   author's declaration
   abstract
   acknowledgement
   table of content
   list of figures
3. then two double space then chapter one
4. then between each chapter single space.
5. how can I put the font size standard for element in chapter one such as background of study and problem statement?

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{report}
\renewcommand*{\contentsname} {\centering \large TABELE OF CONTENTS} % to change the table of content 
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\large\centering LIST OF FIGURES}
\usepackage{tocloft}  % use for th next command in order to remove dots
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{} % remove dots of table of content
\usepackage{indentfirst} % to make indent from first paragraph

\begin{document}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}AUTHOR'S  DECLARATION}

\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}ABSTRACT}%
\include{abstract}
\newpage
\chapter*{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}%
\newpage

\tableofcontents

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}TABEL OF CONTENT}%

\newpage
\listoffigures
addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}LIST OF FIGURES}%


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Is there any help

Comment: Is there any news here?

Answer (score 2):

If i understood the question correctly, you want the following.

[image: texsxTocExxt]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}  % use for th next command in order to remove dots
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{} % remove dots of table of content

\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\cftsecfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\cftsecfont}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Alpha}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bravo}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Charlie}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{\baselineskip}}
\chapter{Animals}
\section{Mara}
\section{Echidna}
\section{Wombat}
\section{Guanaco}
\section{Dinosaur}
\section{Capybara}
\chapter{Legends}
\section{Martin}
\section{Enrico}
\section{Werner}
\section{Gonzalo}
\section{David}
\section{Christian}

\end{document}
```