# How can I customise the table of contents?

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, sectioning

I  am new to LaTeX, please I need you help.
I am writing my thesis and I face problem with table of content, I want to remove the space between the first part of my table of content which is

```
AUTHOR'S DECLARATION i
ABSTRACT ii
ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS iii
TABEL OF CONTENT iv
LIST OF FIGURES v
LIST OF ABBRAVIATIONS
```

Then PUT DOUBLE SPACING using vertical space by 0.5cm
then the second part of table of content appear which is

```
CHAPTER ONE INTRODUCTION 1
1.1 rst section 1
1.2 second section 1
CHAPTER TWO INTRODUCTION 2
2.1 rst section 2
2.2 second section 2
```

Note : between the chapter one and two vertical space by 0.3 cm .
I used as the following:

```
    %\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \documentclass[12pt,english]{report}

    \setlength{\parindent}{1.27cm}

    \usepackage{setspace}
    \onehalfspacing
    \usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}
    \usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,justification=centering]{caption}
    \usepackage{geometry}

    \geometry{
      verbose,
      tmargin=2cm,
      bmargin=2.5cm,
      lmargin=3.8cm,
      rmargin=2.5cm
    }
    \newcommand{\mychapter}[3][]{%
    \setcounter{chapter}{#3}
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \chapter*{#2}
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2}
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
    \fi
    }
\usepackage{tocloft}  % use for th next command in order to remove dots
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{} % remove dots of table of content
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfil\bf} 
    \begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
      \titlespacing*{\chapter}{10pt}{0pt}{10pt}
      \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
          {\centering\normalfont\large\bfseries}{ \chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\large}

          \include{declartion}

          \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{} AUTHOR'S  DECLARATION} \vspace*{-1cm} %

          %\abstract{\addtocontents{toc}

          \newpage

          \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}ABSTRACT} {\vspace*{6cm}}%
          \include{abstract}
          \newpage
          \chapter*{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}%
          \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS} {\vspace{7em}}%
          \newpage

          \tableofcontents

          \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}TABEL OF CONTENT} %{\vspace{-5em}}%

          \newpage
          \listoffigures
          \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}LIST OF FIGURES} %{\vspace{-6em}}%
          \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}LIST OF ABBRAVIATIONS} % {\vspace{-6em}}%
          \newpage


          \newpage
          \tableofcontents

           \titlespacing*{\chapter}{10pt}{0pt}{10pt}
            \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
                {\centering\normalfont\large\bfseries}{ \chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{40pt}{\large}
\mychapter[CHAPTER ONE INTRODUCTION]{CHAPTER ONE\\INTRODUCTION}{1} % the problem if happen fron centering
\pagenumbering{arabic}
sfsdfsf
sfsdfsf
\section{first section}
This is section one in chapter one.
\section{second section }

This is section two  in chapter one.
\mychapter[CHAPTER TWO RELATED WORK]{CHAPTER TWO \\RELATED WORD}{2} % the problem if happen fron centering
\section{first section}
This is section one in chapter TWO.
\section{second section }
This is section two  in chapter TWO.
          \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is this a different question than http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149136/how-can-i-customise-the-table-of-contents-like-so

Comment: This is new way , please any body help me , i spent one week to know that and how to organize my table of content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe some hints from my point of view.

- I can't understand why you are defining the command `\mychapter`. I think you can achieve the same with chapter with some modifications:

  ```
  \titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\centering\normalfont\large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\large}
  \renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
  \setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand\thechapter{}
  ```

  Please Note that you will have a lot of equal section numbers.
- You can work with the package `tocbibind` getting the toc, lof, etc into the table of contents.
- Why do you use `\numberline`? It's result in an usual and unwanted space. Simple:

  ```
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}
  ```
- The space before any chapter entry in the toc is defined by `tocloft` with `\cftbeforechapskip`. So you can change it everywhere with `\addtocontents` (see example)
- Personally I prefer `\clearpage` instead of `newpage`.

BTW Allow me a small hint the a new documentclass like memoir or KOMA. KOMA provides the command `addchap` which makes an unnumbered entry in the toc.

Here your modified MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{report}
\usepackage{setspace}\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}
\usepackage[]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{tocloft} 
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{} % remove dots of table of content
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfil\bf} 
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\centering\normalfont\large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\large}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand\thechapter{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{10pt}{0pt}{10pt}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0em}}%


%\include{declartion}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{AUTHOR'S  DECLARATION}

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ABSTRACT}
\include{abstract}
\clearpage
\chapter*{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}

\clearpage
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF ABBRAVIATIONS}

\clearpage
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{1.0em plus 1pt}}%

\chapter[CHAPTER ONE INTRODUCTION]{CHAPTER ONE\\INTRODUCTION}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
sfsdfsf
sfsdfsf
\section{first section}
This is section one in chapter one.
\section{second section }
This is section two  in chapter one.

\chapter[CHAPTER TWO RELATED WORK]{CHAPTER TWO \\RELATED WORD}
\section{first section}
This is section one in chapter TWO.
\section{second section }
This is section two  in chapter TWO.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for you, really i appreciate your help . But the sections shout be in style of 1.1 that mean in chapter one section one and 1.2 chapter one section two and 2.1 that means chapter two section one and so on. Second thing how can i increase the space between chapter one introduction and list of abbreviation. question three, how can i change content to table of content. my regards to you

Comment: @user1873093: The numbering scheme of `\section` was changed by `\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}`. So simple remove this line and should work. Second issue: Add the following line before chapter one: `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace*{2.0em}}`